# solr indexing is stored in memory or disk

Tags: java, solr

I have about 30GB in memory on server. However, due to large data volume, the indexing takes about 28GB. Is there any way to configure the solr so the indexing of data can be store in hard disk, not in memory? Or if I can assign certain amount of data in memory while the rest in disk?

Comment: Solr stores the index on disk, except for a small buffer of uncommitted documents. Where is the 28GB figure coming from?

Comment: @Steve 28GB is the data indexed in solr. So it's in the hard disk, not memory? I thought it's on the memory to booster the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While indexing data, SolR is creating cache folders and file on the hard drive only.

Memory is just used to:

- index data
- retrieve data
- delete or update data

The strength of SolR is that it creates several indexes to improve data retrieval.